# Emacs compile Python vs. running in shell

Tags: python, shell, emacs

So, as far as I understand it, when I M-x compile my python code, the Compilation buffer isn't really that easy to interact with as opposed to shell or ansi-term.  So if I insert a pdb.set_trace() in my code, I can't debug in the Compilation buffer.  However, what I do like about the Compilation buffer is that when I get the Traceback error I can navigate to all the problem files by just clicking or pressing enter on the referred problem files and even the line in said file.

I came across a blog post talking about enabling compilation-shell-minor-mode in the shell buffer, but that doesn't give me the ability to jump right to the offending file like I get when in the Compilation buffer.  Is there any way I can enable that functionality in something like ansi-term?  I say, ansi-term, because both the Compilation buffer and shell don't really work well with ipython's output for some reason.

EDIT:
I added the code below, and now shell navigates the Traceback source code similar to the Compilation buffer.  I believe it's the goto-address-mode that did the trick.

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'compilation-shell-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda () (highlight-regexp "\\[OK\\]" "hi-green-b")))
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda () (goto-address-mode )))
(require 'ansi-color)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Comment: Try looking here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645401/emacs-python-mode

Comment: Actually, I use the elpy package for programming, this is more specific to running the entire Python library and following the Tracebacks.  I just found my answer, and will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to try `C-u M-x compile` which should give you the usual compilation buffer but with the difference that you can interact with it (it's using compint-mode).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the C-u will disable precisely the feature I'm looking for which is to take me right to the line in the file in the Traceback.  I think I figured it out.

Comment: If th C-u stops the feature that makes you jump to the source when you click on an error message, then I'd recommend you report it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to confirm the same issue?  Right now, I'm just happy that I found my workaround, but if this is legit I'll be more than happy to contribute by reporting the bug.

Comment: I don't see it here, but that doesn't mean what you see isn't real (or *legit*).

Comment: I just updated Emacs, and no longer have that problem.  Thanks for your help, Stefan.